# Bind Class<?> with Guice

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have a List of instances of different classes  and I want to bind each of them to its own class only.
I tried foreach loop with `binder.bind(obj.getClass()).toInstance(obj)`, but ofcourse this does not compile because the compiler is not able to resolve the generic T. 
How else this can be acheived?

Comment: It is very likely that you're doing the things wrong. If your list of instances is statically known, then you should do multiple `bind().toInstance()` calls for each class. If this list is not known in advance, then you should really reconsider your design. Guice is not supposed to be use like that. Look into [multibindings](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings), maybe that is what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need here is a cast to a raw type. As in [chooks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/975497/chooks)'s comment below (thank you!), Guice effectively acts like a map from key (often the class object) to value (Provider of that class), and the generics just help to keep the common case sane. If you're sure that your key matches, you can override the generics like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
  for (Object object : getYourListOfInitializedObjects()) {
    bindObjectAsSingleton(object);
  }
}

/** Suppress warnings to convince the Java compiler to allow the cast. */
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
private void bindObjectAsSingleton(Object object) {
  bind((Class) object.getClass()).toInstance(object);
}
```

As [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788207/vladimir-matveev) mentioned above, this tends not to encourage good Guice design, because even if you have your `DependencyImpl` implement `Dependency`, the above will only create a binding to `DependencyImpl`. Also, all classes in your list of initialized singletons must be created without the benefit of Guice injection themselves, so you're restricting yourself to classes you've initialized externally without Guice's help. You might use the above pattern if you're migrating from a legacy "pile of singletons" into Guice, but you'll probably get farther if you structure your `configure` method like this as soon as possible:

```
@Override
public void configure() {
  // Let Guice create DependencyOne once, with injection,
  // immediately on injector creation.
  bind(DependencyOne.class).asEagerSingleton();

  // Let Guice create DependencyTwo once, with injection,
  // but this way you can hopefully rely on interface DependencyTwo
  // rather than concrete implementation DependencyTwoImpl.
  bind(DependencyTwo.class).to(DependencyTwoImpl.class).asEagerSingleton();

  // Bind DependencyThree to an instance. Instance bindings are
  // implicitly singletons, because you haven't told Guice how to
  // create another one.
  bind(DependencyThree.class).toInstance(getDependencyThreeInstance());

  // ...and so forth for everything in your list.
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. To add a little bit of value to the OP -- if you read up on how guice stores bindings internal with a Key value, then this may make it a little clearer about how to work with generics. I know that I had problems making the conceptual shift with my code (that used a lot of parameterized types/methods/etc...) and finally understanding the actual binding mechanism made things much clearer for resolving issues involving generics and the use of things like TypeLiterals.